# Render custom edit partial in a 'Custom Page' in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin for a project. I have and I have a partial with a custom form. I want to be able to render this custom form when the user clicks in a button so this is what I did:

```
 ActiveAdmin.register_page "Messages" do

    menu priority: 5
    welcome_message = Template.first

    page_action :update, method: :put do
      #update code
    end

    page_action :edit, :method => :get do
      render partial:'custom_form', locals: { settings: welcome_message }
    end

    action_item do
      link_to "Edit", admin_welcome_messages_edit_path, :method => :get
    end

    content do
      render text: "HI"
    end
  end
```

This works, but the problem is that my form gets rendered without the layout and styles of ActiveAdmin, it just shows my `custom_form` as a clean html.

If I render my `custom_form` in the `content do ... end` it does work, but I need that to show something different.

Any help?? I don't know what else to try, I have reached the first 3 pages of google without success!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not find an answer for this but I found a nice workaround that looks pretty good.

In the `action_item`I have a link to `admin_welcome_messages_path` that is the main view and if I'm editing add a param there to show the form instead of the body.

Hope it helps somebody!

```
  ActiveAdmin.register_page "Messages" do

    menu priority: 5
    welcome_message = Template.first

    page_action :update, method: :put do
      #update code
    end

    action_item do
      link_to "Edit", admin_welcome_messages_path(edit: true), :method => :get
    end

    content do
      if params["edit"] == "true"
        render partial:'form', locals: { settings: welcome_message }  
      else
        render partial:'body'
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 7):

kind of an old question but I was having the same problem and this solved it for me.

```
render partial: "name_of_your_partial", layout: "active_admin"
```

wasn't working for me either so I just changed my partial into a template.

```
render: "name_of_your_template", layout: "active_admin"
```

and now the activeadmin layout is being displayed.

Comment: I hit a syntax error when I tried `render: "name_of_your_template", layout: "active_admin"` I had to remove the colon after render, like this:  `render "name_of_your_template", layout: "active_admin"`

Answer (score 0):

Add layout option to the render call.

```
render partial:'custom_form', layout: 'active_admin', locals: { settings: welcome_message }
```

Comment: this did not work, it says it can't find the layout.

Answer (score 0):

> Determine which layout to use.
>
> 1. If we're rendering a standard Active Admin action, we want layout(false)
>         because these actions are subclasses of the Base page (which implements
>         all the required layout code)
> 2. If we're rendering a custom action, we'll use the active_admin layout so
>         that users can render any template inside Active Admin.

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/commit/ce0927661c5991cc857306363c402ef9e283cc42

```
# this would automatically render the custom_edit.html.erb view
page_action :custom_edit do
end

action_item do
  link_to "Custom Edit", admin_welcome_messages_custom_edit_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this an old question but the following worked for me for my Ruby on Rails application:

Inside your `your_custom_page.rb` file do the following

```
content do
   render 'partial_name'
end
```

and place the `_partial_name.erb` in `view/admin/your_custom_page/`

Your partial should now render on that active admin page.